# Interner Serverfehler

Tags: error-message

Interner Serverfehler

Weder Craft\EntryModel noch zugehörige Behavior haben einen Scope "competitionTitel".

what is wrong… it works fine til i delete one point in the menu

Comment: Hi, welcome to Craft CMS Stack Exchange! If at all possible, I'd recommend translating your post to English, as that's what the majority of SE users are fluent in. You're more likely to get a better answer that way. :)

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your templates, you're referencing a custom field `competitionTitel` that doesn't exist. It sounds like you might have recently deleted it.

It will probably look something like `entry.competitionTitel` in your template.  You either need to create that field or adjust your templates to not call it.